# After deploying getting internal server error on heroku

Tags: heroku

Build successfully but still getting internal server error.

Please help to fix this, build message is given below:-

```
-----> Node.js app detected
-----> Creating runtime environment        
NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error       
NODE_VERBOSE=false       
NODE_ENV=production       
NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
-----> Installing binaries       
engines.node (package.json):  10.6.0       
engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)        
Resolving node version 10.6.0...       
Downloading and installing node 10.6.0...       
Using default npm version: 6.1.0
-----> Restoring cache       
Loading 2 from cacheDirectories (default):       
- node_modules       
- bower_components (not cached - skipping)
-----> Building dependencies       
Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)       
audited 492 packages in 2.222s       
found 0 vulnerabilities -----> Caching build       
Clearing previous node cache       
Saving 2 cacheDirectories (default):       
- node_modules       
- bower_components (nothing to cache)
-----> Pruning devDependencies       
removed 66 packages and audited 355 packages in 2.11s       
found 0 vulnerabilities 
-----> Build succeeded!
-----> Discovering process types       
Procfile declares types     -> (none)       
Default types for buildpack -> web
-----> Compressing...       
Done: 22.6M
-----> Launching...       
Released v14       
https://young-forest-74580.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

Comment: When you run `python manage.py runserver` locally, do you get any error?

Comment: I am using node.js -v 10.6.0. Why python ??

Comment: Sorry, I assumed you would be using heroku + django/python. My bad.